# Regex for file extensions, how to understand it

Tags: regex, image

In the **jQuery-File-Upload** and its basic-plus.html demo there is a regex for the file extensions.

`/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i`

`(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i` - second part is obvious matches particular file extensions, case-insensitive.

But what about this part :

```
 (\.|\/)
```

Decimal point is one character, **|** matches either the first or the second part ?

jQuery-File-Upload [basic-plus.html](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/basic-plus.html)

Comment: Note that: `(\.|\/)` is really bad style and is better written as: `([.\/])` which is much more efficient. That first expression is a red flag that whoever wrote this extension has poor regex knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part : `(\.|\/)` mean :

- `\.` : a real dot (escaped), it is **not** the usual dot, which match every character.
- `|` OR
- `\/` a slash (escaped)

So you're catching :

- `.gif`, `/gif`, `.GIF`, `/GIF`...
- `.jpg`, `/jpg`,  `.JPG`, `/JPG`, `.jpeg`, `/jpeg`, `.JPEG`, `/JPEG`...
- `.png`, `/png`, `.PNG`, `/PNG`...

This is used to check both file extension (`.jpg`, `.gif`...) and MimeType (`image/jpeg`, `image/gif`...).

Extract from `jquery.fileupload-validate.js` sources :

```
$.widget('blueimp.fileupload', $.blueimp.fileupload, {

    options: {
        // The regular expression for allowed file types, matches
        // against either file type or file name:
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        ...
    },

    processActions: {
        validate: function (data, options) {
            ...
            // Check  file.type AND file.name
            if (options.acceptFileTypes &&
                !(options.acceptFileTypes.test(file.type) ||
                  options.acceptFileTypes.test(file.name))) {
                file.error = settings.i18n('acceptFileTypes');
            } 
            ...
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: That part seems unneccessary for him.

Comment: Why would an extension check regex care about `/PNG`?

Comment: dot is obvious but why the slash ?

Comment: If you're checking MimeType, you'll have something like `image/jpeg`, `image/gif`, etc... Maybe they check extension **and** MimeType, which would be secured.

Comment: Got it, from `jquery.fileupload-validate.js` source : "The regular expression for allowed file types, matches against either file type or file name". See my edit.